# Primary, Secondary runes on the store page?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any indication whether a rune is "primary" or "secondary" for a specific color, from the rune page in the store?  Obviously that word itself doesn't matter, and just the stats themselves do, but I'm just not seeing any indication of whether the runes in the store are the "ideally suited" runes of a given type/color.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only in-game way to determine numerical ranking is by comparing the values of the mark/seal/glyph directly (A secondary stat will be lower for an equivalent tier rune when compared to a primary stat).

It sucks, but it is what it is.

Fortunately, fanmade data exists which can alleviate this unfortunate design oversight. For this, I point you directly at this page on the [League of Legends Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_runes).

> **Primary Mark:**
>
> - Alacrity (Attack Speed)
> - Desolation (Armor Penetration)
> - Furor (Critical Damage)
> - Insight (Magic Penetration)
> - Malice (Critical Chance)
> - Might (Attack Damage per level)
> - Strength (Attack Damage)
>
> **Primary Seal:**
>    -
>
> - Clarity (Mana Regen / 5 sec per    level)
> - Defense (Armor per level)
> - Evasion (Dodge)
> - Fortitude (Health)
> - Lucidity (Energy Regen / 5 sec per level)
> - Meditation (Energy Regen / 5 sec)
> - Regeneration (Health Regen / 5 sec per level)
> - Replenishment (Mana Regen / 5 sec)
> - Resilience (Armor)
> - Vigor (Health Regen / 5 sec)
> - Vitality (Health per level)
>
> **Primary Glyph:**
>    -
>
> - Acumen (Energy)
> - Celerity (Cooldown per level)
> - Focus (Cooldown)
> - Force (Ability Power per level)
> - Intellect (Mana)
> - Knowledge (Mana per level)
> - Potency (Ability Power)
> - Sapience (Energy per level)
> - Shielding (Magic Resist per level)
> - Warding (Magic Resist)

Comment: Mana regen is Seal? Huh, I never would've actually guessed that. I always figured Mark/Seal/Glyph mirrored the stats from Attack/Defense/Magic in the item shop, respectively.

Comment: Exactly!  Which is part of what brought up this post.  I got confused about that and wanted to make sure the next buys I make are appropriate--although obviously 'appropriate' is dependent upon the situation.