# What do the colors around runes mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “halo” under all my runes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33402/what-is-the-halo-under-all-my-runes)

What does the color surrounding a rune signify on a rune page? I've noticed a red color surrounding some marks and glyphs, and a yellow color surrounding some of my seals. I assume it has something to do with the stat they give or something similar...

Answer (score 0):

Of what I understand, they are all do give about the same number of stats, they are just different categories.

I'm basing that on the fact that all Glyphs, seals, maks and quintessences all have Health bonus, health regen, armor, AD, AP, cooldowns, and other types of bonuses.

But it would be true that every type has its speciality... Glyphs (blues) seem to be a little stronger on the magic effects, seals seem better on the health side and marks seems to be boosting attacks.

I cant tell for Quitessences.